# Need to Refresh the Angular material table after deleting the row based on the index using splice, In my current code only one row is deleting

Tags: javascript, angular

Below code is only removing the last low while deleting in line but not the others, Need to refresh it.

```
   deleteRow(index:any){
      console.log("called", index);
      this.assignForm.controls.splice(index,1);
      this.dataSource = this.assignForm.controls;
      if(index == 0){
        this.disableNext = true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What is the expected behavior? What is happening instead? What exactly do you mean by "refreshing"?

Comment: In case the changes to the array are not applied on the UI: `splice()` modifies the original array, so Angular's change detection mechanism is not able to pick up this change, as the reference is still the same.

Comment: Maybe you need to set the dataSource first to null and then set the new value or you need to use the `ChangeDetectorRef`. I am not sure right now, but one of those two suggestions should work.

Comment: @SebastianS. I think it would be better to create a new array with the spread operator: `this.dataSource = [...this.assignForm.controls];`

Comment: @JSONDerulo The issue is when I have more than one row in a table and I'm trying to delete from the last one by one, ten I'm able to only delete the last one, rest are not deleting or not getting removed from UI.

Comment: @NeetiJain next step for you is to perform more research. Is it a problem with your logic in TypeScript, or is just the view not properly updated? Or is it a problem with your TypeScript logic and the wrong array is being modified? It's too early to ask such question with on StackOverflow. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: @JSONDerulo spread operator is working fine.

Comment: @JSONDerulo yep, you are right, that is the better option.